# Extracting files from busted Android phone

Tags: usb, android

I have a busted android phone, manufactured by a brazilian company. It broke within five months, but it still hold lots of info (such as contacts and apps) that I'd like to retrieve.
They are not in the SD card, they are written in the hardware's 8GB. 
I tried to connect a USB cable to extract the data, but nothing happens (Is that because the Loader mounts the USB drive?).

Is there a way of accessing the internal HD to gather the data?

Comment: No, your mobile should be working to allow you to have an access to the internal storage.

Comment: ... Hmm... considering it is not, I think I should move this question to a hardware-based-stack-overflow to attempt it the... well.. **hard** way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a precious data in there then go for the recovery, it costs expensive, I believe they will unsolder the flash chip and put it to the special reader (or/and solder again) or they can try to fix a mobile phone first. But anyways to get storage from the mobile or from computer connected to this mobile phone it shall be turned on, powered on and have the drivers an applications level  running.